# Copy id after insert to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, but I would like to set a trigger. When I insert a new user to my table `users`, I would like to copy that `id` to another table: `results`.

Table `users`:

```
| userID | name     | email             | password |
+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
| 1      | Person A | mailA@gmail.com   | 12345    |
+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
| 2      | Person B | mailB@yahoo.com   | 13579    |
+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
| 3      | Person C | mailC@outlook.com | 24681    |
+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
```

Table `results`:

```
| resultID | userID | TestA | TestB |
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 162      | 1      | 84    | 63    |
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 028      | 2      | NULL  | 54    |
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 821      | 3      | 77    | 60    |
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to copy the `userID` from table `users` to `userID` in table `results` after insert.
I tried various options with triggers, but nothing fixed my problems.

One of them is:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER T_TableA_I
on users
after insert
as
    set nocount on

    insert into results (userID)
    select u.UserID
    from
        users u
            inner join
        results r
            on
                u.UserID = r.UserID
```

It may be that my structure is not in accordance with the guidelines, but this is a concept.

Comment: So have you created a trigger?

Comment: I tried various options found on StackOverflow and other platform, but nothing suits my needs.

Comment: And what are your needs?

Comment: ' I would like to copy that id' - do you mean insert, upsert or what?

Comment: I would like to copy the `userID` from table `users` to `userID` in table `results` after insert.

Comment: What are TestA and TestB columns used for? Why not one common test results column, and another one specifying the result - which means two rows if both A and B are done.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be interesting to see your attempts, and know about the problems with them

Comment: That's about the easiest trigger imaginable so I am struggling to see what the problem could be. Please add your attempted trigger and explain why it's not achieving what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I added my best try so far. But now, my registration form for `users` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: `INSERT into results SET userID = NEW.id`

Comment: The published code is nowhere near correct syntactically or conceptually - You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html. AND I am baffled as to what the insert select is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure if I understand the question but here's a code snippet for conversation

```
drop table if exists us,res;
create table us (id int);
create table res (id int);

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on us
for each row
begin
    insert into res(id) values (new.id);
end $$

delimiter ;

insert into us values (1);
select * from us;
 +------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

select * from res;

+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `drop table` scares me a little. 
It's about adding a row to the `results` table with the `userID` of the new row in `users` after inserting to the `users` table.

Comment: gies a break..This is sample code to prove my code works. You absolutely should not blindly cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following code snippet, but I could not figure out where to get the test result!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
userID INT(6) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255),
password VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results (
resultID INT(6) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
userID VARCHAR(255),
TestA VARCHAR(255),
TestB VARCHAR(255)
);

/* trigger query */
CREATE TRIGGER new_user_added 
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO results values('162', NEW.userID, '84', '63');

/* insert query */
replace into users values('1', 'Person A', 'mailA@gmail.com', '12345');

select * from users;
select * from results
```

users

```
| userID | name     | email             | password |
+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
| 1      | Person A | mailA@gmail.com   | 12345    |
+--------+----------+-------------------+----------+
```

results

```
| resultID | userID | TestA | TestB |
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
| 162      | 1      | 84    | 63    |
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Hope this could help.